# Почему программа не запустилась?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, nasm

Всех приветствую, не давно начал изучать ассемблер и написал простую программу

```
section .data

    msg db "Hello world", 0x0a, 0x0d
    len equ $ - msg

section .text

        global _start

_start:

    mov rax, 4
    mov rbx, 1
    mov rcx, msg
    mov rdx, len

    int 0x80

    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0

    int 0x80
```

но потом решил поэкспериментировать и поменять регистры `rax` на `rdx` так как я прочитал то что они используются для временных переменных цп

и поменял регистры местами то есть

```
section .data

    msg db "Hello world", 0x0a, 0x0d
    len equ $ - msg

section .text

        global _start

_start:

    mov rdx, 4
    mov rax, 1
    mov rcx, msg
    mov rax, len

    int 0x80

    mov rdx, 1
    mov rax, 0

    int 0x80
```

программа скомпилировалась

но при запуске ничего не выводит с чем это связано ??

Comment: Почитайте что-нибудь про int 0x80, нельзя же так вслепую   "изучать ассемблер".. Вот тут есть аналогичный код, но хотя бы с комментариями https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~bismith/test/syscalls/syscalls.html , должно что-то прояснить.

Comment: Вам бы начать с документа, который описывает ABI конкретной архитектуры. (Подсказка: ОС тут идёт во вторую очередь)

Comment: @A.Toumantsev, 0andriy Большое спасибо